# Wifi not working after using tuya-convert

Tags: wireless

I intended to flash a firmware on one of my home devices using "tuya-convert". I basically installed a few dependencies, then ran a script that used my Ubuntu 18 notebook as a hotspot for the smart device. Sadly, after rebooting, my wifi stopped working. It cannot find any networks and seems to be down. I've been trying a bunch of things and googling a lot, but I couldnn't find the solution. Ethernet still works.

ifconfig output:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::f14a:9a76:388e:9ef5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::b554:8b13:68ab:161c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00::ac63:a23b:daaf:30c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 54:ee:75:9b:9e:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3104  bytes 1484783 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2071  bytes 472941 (472.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

No Wifi showing up.

iwconfig outputs:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::f14a:9a76:388e:9ef5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::b554:8b13:68ab:161c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00::ac63:a23b:daaf:30c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 54:ee:75:9b:9e:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3104  bytes 1484783 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2071  bytes 472941 (472.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lshw -C network:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::f14a:9a76:388e:9ef5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::b554:8b13:68ab:161c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00::ac63:a23b:daaf:30c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 54:ee:75:9b:9e:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3104  bytes 1484783 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2071  bytes 472941 (472.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 676  bytes 63421 (63.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It says that wifi is deactivated. It's enabled in the settings. Flight mode is off of course.

iwlist wlp3s0 scan outputs:

```
wlp3s0    Failed to read scan data : Network is down
```

Running "ifconfig wlp3s0 up" and redoing "iwlist wlp3s0 scan" just outputs "No scan results".

rfkill list all

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also tried mounting the Ubuntu ISO and going into the update center and check "additional drivers", but it didn't need anything (while connected via ethernet).

As you can see, I've tried tons of things. Does anybody have a clue what's going on?

This is what I did to flash the firmware onto the smart home device that messed up everything:

```
git clone https://github.com/ct-Open-Source/tuya-convert

cd tuya-convert
sudo ./install_prereq.sh
```

(installs `dnsmasq` `hostapd` `screen` `curl` `python3-pip` `python3-setuptools` `python3-wheel` `mosquitto` `haveged` `net-tools` AND runs `sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt pyaes tornado`)

then I ran

```
https://github.com/ct-Open-Source/tuya-convert/blob/master/start_flash.sh
```

and got until line 66. Maybe line 60 is interesting here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please format outputs and errors as code using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: Thanks! I tried [code], but that didn't work :P